# How to tell if NSData is actually an NSImage?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata, nsimage

I'm sending data back and forth through the Bonjour protocol. All the packets are sent as `NSData` and usually converted to strings; but what if I need to receive an image? This is the process that will be going on.

1. Client requests the `NSImage`
2. Server sends the requested `NSImage` as a `NSData` packet
3. Client receives `NSData`
4. Client checks if the data is an image
5. ????
6. PROFIT?

Could I attempt to convert the data into an image and catch the error (which would mean it's not an image)?

Comment: have you tried. `if([data isKindOfClass:[NSImage class]]){}`

Comment: @janusfidel: haha ;) NSData is never an NSImage, even if it contains image-data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

If `data` is not valid image data, then `image` will be `nil`.